# Calculating a sports teams "streak" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a sports teams winning and losing streak over the season given whether they won, lost, or tied using R.

Given this data (the results of the team over the season, with 1 being a win and 0 being a loss) I wanted to show their current streak after each game. So we can see what kind of streak they have coming into the next game they play.

> data <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1) %>% as.data.frame()

[The results should look like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S77Dt.png)

So far I have tried to generate case statements while using the cumsum function, however those statements break down after the result changes from a 1 to 0 or vice versa.

The problem is that the cumsum function continues to sum over all results, and so when a team wins a game after losing the previous one, its streak should be 1 entering the following game, instead the cumsum function continues to count from the last winning streak, and reports a streak of 5 or 6.

The goal is to reset the cumsum function after a team wins or loses.

Comment: @caldwellst notice that with this question, the zeros are subtracted while the ones are added, so still different from the link you included

Comment: Use  `rle`   .  The answer is always to use `rle` :-) .  Then you can do `cumsum` on each element of   `rle(stuff)$lengths`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left in a couple helper columns for clarity, but you can of course drop them if you don't want them in the result.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  setNames("x") %>%
  group_by(run_id = data.table::rleid(x)) %>%
  mutate(cur_streak = row_number() * ifelse(x == 0, -1, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(streak = lag(cur_streak, default = 0))
# # A tibble: 16 × 4
#        x run_id cur_streak streak
#    <dbl>  <int>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1      1          1      0
#  2     1      1          2      1
#  3     1      1          3      2
#  4     1      1          4      3
#  5     1      1          5      4
#  6     1      1          6      5
#  7     1      1          7      6
#  8     1      1          8      7
#  9     0      2         -1      8
# 10     1      3          1     -1
# 11     1      3          2      1
# 12     1      3          3      2
# 13     0      4         -1      3
# 14     0      4         -2     -1
# 15     1      5          1     -2
# 16     1      5          2      1
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```
c(0, head(ave(2*data[,1]-1,cumsum(c(1,!!diff(data[,1]))), FUN = cumsum), -1))
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 -1  1  2  3 -1 -2  1
```

in Data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setNames(setDT(data), "v")[, .(v,streak = cumsum(2 * v - 1)), rleid(v)
   ][,.(result = v, streak = c(0, streak[-.N]))]

    result streak
 1:      1      0
 2:      1      1
 3:      1      2
 4:      1      3
 5:      1      4
 6:      1      5
 7:      1      6
 8:      1      7
 9:      0      8
10:      1     -1
11:      1      1
12:      1      2
13:      0      3
14:      0     -1
15:      1     -2
16:      1      1
```

Comment: Impressive base solution!